# Change font size with UISlider

Tags: iphone, uislider

I am trying to change the font size of my UITextView using the value from a UISlider.
i need some tips or sample code :)
thank you .

Comment: Asking for help "writing all of codes" is not going to get you any help.
You need to show that you've at least *tried* to make an effort. As far as I can tell you're trying to get other people to do all the work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a `UISlider`.
2. Add your view controller as a target
   for `UISlider'`s value changed event,
   i.e.:

   ```
   [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderActionHandler:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   ```
3. Change the font size inside this handler.